# How to programing fingerprint with raspberray pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

I have KOOKYE fingerprint scanner

Device:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B019TPP1UK/ref=s9_simh_gw_g147_i1_r?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=0SHK4RN0THZ4NGT6PR3G&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=026d359a-cb34-4790-9249-ec9f152ee8e2&pf_rd_i=desktop

I want to connect it to Raspberry Pi 3, but the only library available for this device is for Arduino. 
Library: 
http://kookye.com/2016/07/24/use-arduino-drive-fingerprint-sensor/

Which is the best way to use the scanner on raspberry pi? Do I need to rewrite the library or I can use an Arduino emulator on Pi? If an emulator is used, how do you make the emulator to listen to the Serial port of the Arduino and which would be better to use?